# How to get large Windows dialog icons for high-dpi screens?

Tags: winapi

I currently use [SHGetStockIconInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shellapi/nf-shellapi-shgetstockiconinfo) to get default Windows dialog icons like Warning, Error, Help or Info. Unfortunately, it only supports 16px (small) and 32px (large) icons even on high-dpi screens. On a screen with 200% scaling, I would need these icons with 64px.

I found alternative API methods to get system icons, but none of them seem to support high-dpi, i.e. larger sizes.

What is the correct way to get large Windows dialog icons?

Comment: Does passing the [`SHGSI_SHELLICONSIZE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shellapi/nf-shellapi-shgetstockiconinfo#shgsi_shelliconsize) flag change the observed behavior?

Comment: I'm already using exactly that flag. So unfortunately no.

Comment: use [`LoadIconWithScaleDown`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/commctrl/nf-commctrl-loadiconwithscaledown)

Comment: YES! Thanks a lot! Didn't know that this method could also be used for loading default system icons. Would you like to post it as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: @CodeX Also, you can [answer your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Comment: The comment of @RbMm already contains the answer. I don't think it's fair to "steal" it, is it?

Comment: @CodeX Yes, I agree with you. But if RbMm doesn't have time to write an answer, you can write an answer pointing out which commenter helped you find the right direction/solution etc. And add more helpful information to make it be a quality answer which will help this question-answer to be more clear and helpful for people are searching on similar issue. Of course, this is just a suggestion. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@RbMm provided the perfect suggestion as a comment. To close this question, I'm adding it here as an answer.

[LoadIconWithScaleDown](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/commctrl/nf-commctrl-loadiconwithscaledown) does the job perfectly. It loads the icon in the specified standard size without any scaling (or scales a non-standard size down from a larger available size). It can be used to load system images just as well:

> If hinst is NULL, pszName specifies either the name of a standalone
>   icon (.ico) file or the identifier of a predefined icon to load. The
>   following identifiers are recognized. To pass these constants to the
>   LoadIconWithScaleDown function, use the MAKEINTRESOURCE macro. For
>   example, to load the IDI_ERROR icon, pass MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_ERROR)
>   as the pszName parameter and NULL as the hinst parameter.